# Find which version of reactJS does react-native use?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to find the version or reactJS that is being used by the react-native I am using to develop native apps?

Answer (score 2):

In your /node_modules/react-native/package.json file, you'll see the version

Comment: There isn't any. There are packages called react-tools and react-timer-mixin but no react

Comment: On, sorry... I misunderstood your question. My bad. I think you have to look in the release notes to find out which react version is used. I also believe they intend to improve this. See v0.15.0-rc release notes to learn that it uses react 0.14 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.15.0-rc

Comment: I was looking for which version of reactJs does react-native 0.14 uses to find out if it uses react 0.14 or not. Since it will be included in 0.15.0-rc, it answers my question. They don't make it easy to figure it out though.